# My internet service provider spying on me?

Tags: dns-spoofing

I have found when I ping "www.google.com" the response is an ip address of my country location, not Google. The strange thing is the site opens normally. Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Google has servers in several countries. Probably including yours. Just because the IP address isn't from America doesn't mean that it's not Google.

Comment: @l1thal do you have any sources about google servers in contries

Comment: Google it. Please do your research before asking a question.

Comment: Also do a search for how Google handles pings vs how it handles web traffic.

Comment: @l1thal no google servers in africa

Comment: @MRRobot it has cache servers in africa http://www.balancingact-africa.com/news/en/issue-no-568/computing/google-cache-servers/en

Comment: Please add some evidence about what you found otherwise it is just guessing about what is going on.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LGpSq.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/KeWkD.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/gigiX.png

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are spying, but we can explain why is not google which respond to your ping.

In my entreprise, we can access to Internet by differents proxies and security systems. If I try to ping google with a console from my Windows 7 PC (x.x.32.115), I will not receive any response. But if I open wireshark and retry pinging google, I see I receive a response of my ping (ICMP type 0) from the server (x.y.166.62) of my enterprise and not directly from google's server. Moreover, I never receive the DNS requests for externals domains of my entreprise.

In fact, this server has a DNS service and it could act as a proxy or firewall.

For your question, the answer you receive is probably the response of a proxy or a security system of your ISP.
[image]

Comment: how about i see whatsapp hangouts apps their ip is same as the google respond ip ???

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LGpSq.png

Comment: Because whatsapp is a web service which is intercepted by the same proxy of your question.